# Repeating Dates in a Lotus Appointment document generated by LotusScript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

In a course Registration application (.nsf web application), users register for courses. Upon registration, a LousScript QuerySave agent generates and sends an appointment document to the recipient. Information includes Start Time, End Time, location, Time Zone information ect. All users of the system have MS Exchange email accounts and use the Outlook mail client.

Issue: When a multi-day course is created and users register, the calendar shows the block of time for the course as being from the start time of the first date to the end time of the end dates. I am unable to grammatically generate an appointment in Domino with repeating dates that displays correctly in Outlook.

Creating a repeating date meeting in a Notes Mail Client and including a user with an Outlook client functions correctly. Mimicking all of the fields in the Meeting document in a LotusScript agent does not generate an appointment that displays correctly (repeating appointment).

Question: Has anyone had success in creating multi-day repeating date appointments in LotusScript? I have been heavily testing different ways of approaching this, but have had no success.

Comment: Is this question correctly tagged? It doesn't appear that this is related to XPages.

Comment: What version of Domino? In older version the first occurrence was created immediately, an agent was creating the entries for the repeating days.

Comment: Current version Domino 8.5.3. Question: Has anyone had success in creating multi-day repeating date appointments in LotusScript? I have been heavily testing different ways of approaching this, but have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here to check the Fix List for 9.0.1](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/Public?OpenView&Start=1&Count=30&ExpandView) - - It seems to have a few C&S fixes and some relating to Outlook.